# Gitlab Pages in docker with reverse-proxy

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have docker gitlab instance at `gitlab.example.io`. So i configured in gitlab.rb:

```
pages_external_url "http://pages.example.io"
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
```

Both `gitlab.example.io` and `pages.example.io` at the same ip address.

Then I create simple example group with `group_test` name and `group_nested` inside. Finaly I create project with name `project_test` in group_nested.

It contains index.html

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World!</p>
</body>
```

and .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - deploy

pages:
  tags:
    - latest
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - mkdir .public
    - cp -r * .public
    - mv .public public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - main
```

After pipeline finishes I get url: `http://group_test.pages.example.io/group_nested/project_test` and when I try to follow the link I get `404 error. Not found. The requested URL was not found on this server`.
Files exist at `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-rails/shared/pages`.
DNS service has wildcard record `*.example.io A ip-address`.
Gitlab pages log:

```
==> /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-pages/current <==
{"level":"info","msg":"Checking GitLab internal API availability","time":"2021-09-19T21:21:40+03:00"}
{"error":"failed to connect to internal Pages API: HTTP status: 502","level":"warning","msg":"attempted to connect to the API","time":"2021-09-19T21:21:40+03:00"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Checking GitLab internal API availability","time":"2021-09-19T21:21:44+03:00"}
{"error":"failed to connect to internal Pages API: HTTP status: 502","level":"warning","msg":"attempted to connect to the API","time":"2021-09-19T21:21:44+03:00"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Checking GitLab internal API availability","time":"2021-09-19T21:21:49+03:00"}
{"error":"failed to connect to internal Pages API: HTTP status: 502","level":"warning","msg":"attempted to connect to the API","time":"2021-09-19T21:21:49+03:00"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Checking GitLab internal API availability","time":"2021-09-19T21:21:55+03:00"}
{"error":"failed to connect to internal Pages API: HTTP status: 502","level":"warning","msg":"attempted to connect to the API","time":"2021-09-19T21:21:55+03:00"}
{"level":"info","msg":"Checking GitLab internal API availability","time":"2021-09-19T21:22:03+03:00"}
{"level":"info","msg":"GitLab internal pages status API connected successfully","time":"2021-09-19T21:22:03+03:00"}
```

Answer (score 1):

My latest config for gitlab 16.x.x

```yaml
GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        ### Web interface settings
        external_url "https://gitlab.domain.org"
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
        nginx['listen_https'] = false

        ### Pages
        gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
        pages_external_url "https://pages.domain.org"
        pages_nginx['ssl'] = false
        pages_nginx['listen_https'] = false
        gitlab_pages['listen_proxy'] = '0.0.0.0:8090'
        gitlab_pages['internal_gitlab_server'] = 'http://localhost:8080'
```

This is a configuration for 1 docker container, which stays behind a reverse proxy(nginx/traefik/whatever). If you terminate https(TLS) on the load balancer it proxies traffic to HTTP ports: 80 - gitlab, 8090 - pages.